# Extracting different types of data from a file and save these values in variables

Tags: bash, awk, grep, command

I have a file like

```
water
{
    nu              1.69e-3;
    rho             8;
}
vapour
{
    rho             2;
}
right
{
    type            zeroGradient 6;
    value           uniform (40 10 0);  

}

left
{
    value           uniform (0 5 0);    
}
```

and I want to extract the values `1.69e-3`, `8,2`, `40`, `5` from it and save these values in variables separately. To extract `8` and `2` and save them in variables I use the following commands,

```
rhol=`grep rho file | awk '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/;//g' | head -1`
rhog=`grep -m2 rho file | awk '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/;//g' | tail -n1`
```

But to get the scientific value of `1.69e-3`, and two other values `40` and `5` I have problem to get the values.

Comment: assuming the objective is to save these values in variables, please update the question to show the variable names and associated values

Comment: How would we know which number to extract from the `uniform` lines?

Comment: That's my question actually, I want to get access to the value 40 in the first uniform line and save it to a variable (for example U1X) and then again do the same for the value 5  in the second uniform line and save it in another variable (for example U2Y).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify this within the question itself.

Comment: As an aside, Awk can do everything `grep` and `sed` can do (and really, `head` and `tail` too); see [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple Awk parser which outputs assignments you can `eval`. You will want to make very sure the output is what you expect before you actually do that.

```
awk 'BEGIN { insec=0 }
/[^{]/ && NF==1 && !insec { sec=$1; next }
/[{]/ && sec { insec=1; next }
/[}]/ && insec { sec=""; insec=0; next }
insec && !/^[ \t]*(value|type)/ && NF>1 { sub(/;$/, ""); printf "%s_%s=%s\n", sec, $1, $NF }
insec && /^[ \t]*value/ { gsub(/[();]+/, ""); for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s_%i=%s\n", sec, i-2, $i }' "$@"
```

Save this as a script; running it on the file should produce something like

```
water_nu=1.69e-3
water_rho=8
vapour_rho=2
right_1=40
right_2=10
right_3=0
left_1=0
left_2=5
left_3=0
```

As requested in a comment, this splits up the `uniform` fields into separate values `left_1`, `left_2` etc. (But really, please make sure your question itself is complete and well-defined. Comments could be deleted at any time.)

Once the results are what you want, you'd run it like

```
eval "$(yourscript yourfile)"
```

to have the shell evaluate the assignments it outputs.

Demo: https://ideone.com/hGPsTE

As ever, be very paranoid before actually using `eval`. There is probably a much better way to do what you ask; I would suggest implementing the rest of the logic in Awk too if feasible.

Comment: A better solution still is to parse this format into JSON and take it from there. Yet better still would be to convince who or whatever produces this godforsaken ad-hoc format to write the information in a standard format in the first place. Life is too short to write parsers, especially quick and dirty ones.

Comment: i updated this answer to split the uniform fields into subscripted subfields. (Stack Overflow will notify you of new comments, but not when an answer is updated.)

Comment: If you put your awk in a function `getValues` you can source the output with `source <(getValues)` and get all assignments  without `eval`

Answer (score 2):

Using Bash 4 / Associative Array / awk

```
#!/bin/bash

reformatText(){
    # format input text to [parent_key,child_key]="value"  
    awk '
        /{|}/ {next} 
        !/^ / {parent_key=$1; next}
        {
            child_key=$1; $1=""; gsub(/^ |;|)|\(/,"")
            if(child_key=="value"){ 
                for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
                    printf "[%s,%s,%s]=\"%s\"\n", parent_key, child_key, i, $i  
            }else{
                printf "[%s,%s]=\"%s\"\n", parent_key, child_key, $0
            }
        }
        ' input_file 
}


    
arrayValues="$(reformatText)"
declare -A myArray="($arrayValues)"
   
echo "${myArray[water,nu]}"
echo "${myArray[vapour,rho]}"
echo "${myArray[water,rho]}"
echo "${myArray[right,value,2]}"
echo "${myArray[left,value,3]}"
```

Output:

```
1.69e-3
2
8
40
5
```

Reformated text:

```
[water,nu]="1.69e-3"
[water,rho]="8"
[vapour,rho]="2"
[right,type]="zeroGradient 6"
[right,value,1]="uniform"
[right,value,2]="40"
[right,value,3]="10"
[right,value,4]="0"
[left,value,1]="uniform"
[left,value,2]="0"
[left,value,3]="5"
[left,value,4]="0"
```

Array content:

```
declare -A myArray=([right,type]="zeroGradient 6" [right,value,2]="40" [right,value,3]="10" [right,value,1]="uniform" [right,value,4]="0" [left,value,1]="uniform" [left,value,3]="5" [left,value,2]="0" [left,value,4]="0" [vapour,rho]="2" [water,nu]="1.69e-3" [water,rho]="8" )
```

---

Second approach without array

```
reformatText2(){
    # format input text to parent_key,child_key,...="value"  
    awk '
        /{|}/ {next} 
        !/^ / {parent_key=$1; next}
        {
            child_key=$1; $1=""; gsub(/^ |;|)|\(/,"")
            if(child_key=="value"){ 
                for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
                    printf "%s_%s_%s=\"%s\"\n", parent_key, child_key, i, $i  
            }else{
                printf "%s_%s=\"%s\"\n", parent_key, child_key, $0
            }
        }
        ' input_file
}

source <(reformatText2)
echo "${water_nu}"
echo "${water_rho}"
echo "${vapour_rho}"
echo "${right_value_2}"
echo "${left_value_3}"
```

Output

```
1.69e-3
8
2
40
5
```

show all assignments

```
reformatText2

water_nu="1.69e-3"
water_rho="8"
vapour_rho="2"
right_type="zeroGradient 6"
right_value_1="uniform"
right_value_2="40"
right_value_3="10"
right_value_4="0"
left_value_1="uniform"
left_value_2="0"
left_value_3="5"
left_value_4="0"
```

Comment: If you have a new enough Bash, associative arrays are defintely preferrable over e.g. `eval`; but this feature was introduced in Bash 4, which is not available out of the box on e.g. MacOS.

Comment: @tripleee.. You're right.. Forgot to mention Bash 4..

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you want from looking at your sample:

- lines that do not have the word uniform, the number in the line (what precedes the `;`).
- lines that have uniform, the number(s) between parenthesis, if not equal to 0.

You can do this with `awk`:

```
/uniform/ {
    numbers = gensub(/.*\((.*)\);/, "\\1", "g", $0)
    split(numbers, numbersarray, " ")
    for (i in numbersarray) {
        if (numbersarray[i] != 0) {
            print numbersarray[i]
        }
    }
}
/;$/ && ! /zeroGradient;/ {
    t=length($2)
    print substr($2,0,t-1)
}
```

Save this to `file.awk` and run using `awk -f file.awk inputfile.txt`

---

**For lines with `/uniform/`**

- extract the numbers.  They are what is seen between `( )` in the line.  `gensub` is used here, it works similar to `sed 's///'`.  The `\(` are the ones found in the text, the `(` are used to define the value of `\\1` used later.
- then split the numbers string into an array.
- loop on the array, any number that != 0 is printed to the screen.

`gensub` details:

- `/.*\((.*)\);/`
- `//` delimit a pattern
- `.*` will match anything (0 or more of any char)
- `\(` the parenthesis after `uniform`
- `\);` the closing parenthesis with the `;`
- `(.*)` anything between parenthesis, and set that in field no.1 for the replacement.

---

**For lines that end with `;` AND not the lines with `zeroGradient`**

- print the second field in the line, removing the `;` at the end.

The output using this is:

```
1.69e-3
8
2
40
5
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, which was great. I think I wasn't clear in my question, but I wanted to get values and then save them in variables. The question is edited now. I found your answer to be very helpful and learned a lot from it.